# Laravel order by child in the same table

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a thread table with replies in the same table named posts:

```
       ID  |  PARENT_ID  | CATEGORY_ID |  CREATED_AT  | UPDATED_AT
```

If the "PARENT_ID" not null then is a thread otherwise is a reply.

With a "CATEGORY_ID=3" i want to get all threads **with pagination** ordered by "UPDATED_AT" of last reply if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is not to go in this direction but rather update the parent when creating a child using the method:

```
$parent->touch();
```

with this solution we don't need to look for the children to know the order of the parents